# Using UIImage imageNamed inside XCTestCase

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, uiimage, xctest

I can't get XCTestCase unit tests for a Cocoa Touch Static Library which rely on code that uses `imageNamed` to work.

I added my image "plane.png" to the test target, but `[UIImage imageNamed]` keeps returning nil.
When I explicitly specify the path of the image in the test and load the image from file it does work.

```
NSString* imagePath = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"plane.png"];
UIImage* imageWorks = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

UIImage* imageStaysNil = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plane.png"];
```

How can I write unit tests for code that uses `imageNamed`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In XCTest you aren't in mainBundle. So get your image from your XCTest bundle.

(this solution is for iOS8+)

#### ObjC

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"..." inBundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
```

#### Swift

```
UIImage(named: "...", in: Bundle(for: type(of: self)), compatibleWith: nil)
```

Comment: This new function does use the system image cache, unlike `imageWithContentsOfFile`, so in iOS8+ it's possible to test. Having to change all `imageNamed` calls simply to be able to unit test the code is not ideal though, but it'll do.

Comment: @Fonix in swift 4.0, 4.1 and 4.2, `type(of: self)` works fine, no need to change it.

Comment: @Cœur you are right, it does work, im not sure what i did earlier but it was giving me a compile error and coincidentally changing the `type(of: self)` got it to work for me so i just assumed it was that, maybe was just xcodes error warnings not updating in a timely fashion

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work for me; here's what did.

```
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: 
    Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    .path(forResource: "plane", ofType: "png")!)!
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your xctest project acts like different project It's mandatory to add your .png file for xctest also.

add your plane.png  image to xctest project also.
Make sure you have checked like

[image]

It works fine for me with the same code

[image]

Comment: The image is added to the test target (I don't think the loading from file would work if it weren't?)

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I'm testing a "cocoa touch static library", so the resource can't be added to the static library itself, maybe that's the difference?

Comment: is your image added to static library?

Comment: No, you can't really add resources to a static library, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html

Comment: I created a new application project, and there it does indeed work, but not for a static library. Clarified the question, thanks for helping me narrow the problem down

Comment: I know that you can't include the image or any other resources in static library. But you can have them in library project. When you dragging your library you should add your image/Resource/Asset to the main project. In that sense i asked

Comment: Well, you can't, really, try it. You can check the box when you add the file and if you then inspect your file it will no longer be checked for the library itself but only for the test target.